# sbt Resolve Error in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to open a scala sbt project
https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/websocket-akka-http

but the following `Resolve Error` occurs:

[image]

In addition the `Show log` link does nothing (*really impressive, that ..*)

Note that this project is already building and running from the command line using `sbt run`

Out of curiosity I took a look at which versions of `sbt` were installed on the machine: we have 13.11:

```
$ll /usr/local/Cellar/sbt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    5 macuser  admin   170 Jun 10 09:47 0.13.11
```

But in any case it is the responsibility of IJ to manage the sbt versions if it needs versions differing from the ones in the project or installed on the host.

Anyone seen this /have a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Intellij IDEA install has apparently been configured to use a custom SBT launcher. If you do that, it's your responsibility to update Intellij's configuration if the path to the SBT launcher installed on your computer changes (and since you apparently use homebrew to install SBT, the install path includes the version number, so it will change for each SBT version update).

If you want Intellij to use its own choice of SBT launcher, you need to change back the configuration to the default value: in Preferences>Build, Execution, Deployment>SBT>Launcher, choose "Bundled" instead of "Custom".

Comment: It's a nearly new computer - and I do not recall having set to custom sbt launcher Will check!  Thx for the suggestion in any case - will upvote now.

Comment: Interesting thing happened - I am going to create a separate answer .. but will award to you.

Comment: Note that the configuration is probably in your user directory, so if you copied your user data from a previous computer (manually or with Apple's migration assistant), and if you already had Intellij + Scala plugin installed on the old computer, you may have carried over an old setting? If there is no existing user setting at all, the default is definitely "Bundled".

Answer (score 1):

So **here's what happened** . I **imported settings** from another machine. And apparently the `sbt` settings were imported as well.

[image]

That was confusing!  Giving credit to @Cyaegha for pointing out the custom sbt launcher issue.